# I have a form with select which creates elements. How I can do that elements creates only once?

Tags: javascript, html, select, input

I have JS code which creates paragraph and input elements according to html. But I need this code to create each element only once.

Peace of Javascript code

```
function comFunction(sel) {
   switch (sel.value) {
        case 'skype':
            var skype = document.createElement("P");
            var temp = document.createTextNode("Enter your skype");
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "text";
            skype.appendChild(temp);
            form.appendChild(skype);
            form.appendChild(input);
            break;
}
```

HTML code

```
<form id="form">
<select name="liason" id="liason" onchange="comFunction(this);">
    <option value="skype">Skype</option>
    <option value="icq">ICQ</option>
    <option value="facebook">Facebook</option>
    <option value="email">e-mail</option>
</select>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an id to the elements being created and appended to the DOM, you can then check for their existence before running the code that would create them a second time:

```
 function comFunction(sel) {

   switch (sel.value) {
    case 'skype':
        if(document.getElementById("skypeParagraph") === null) {
           var skype = document.createElement("P");
           skype.setAttribute("id", "skypeParagraph");
           var temp = document.createTextNode("Enter your skype");
           var input = document.createElement("input");
           input.type = "text";
           skype.appendChild(temp);
           form.appendChild(skype);
           form.appendChild(input);
        }
        break;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to add more than 10 kinds of connection, I have to add 10 more IDes?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Each main element that gets created would get created with an id (or class) that you can then check to see if it exists later when the code is attempting to create the element. Also, giving an element an id is very helpful down the line for a variety of reasons (easy to get in JS as this solution shows, easy to write a CSS selector against it as well).